# Error while copying data from Python to Postgressql

Tags: python, postgresql, copy

While copying data from CSV file to Postgressql, I am getting an error

> psycopg2.errors.BadCopyFileFormat: extra data after last expected column

I have a CSV file that contains millions of records and has to be loaded oin Postgressql as part of ETL process. There are total 10 columns in the file. Reading the headers is working fine but while copying the data error comes up.

There looks to be ',' in the data itself and which is making the copy command assume there is more data. Not sure how to handle such data.

```py
conn = pg.connect("host =localhost dbname=postgres user=postgres password=password")
    cur = conn.cursor ()
    with open ( 'data.csv', 'r' ) as f:
        next ( f )  # Skipping the header row.
        cur.copy_from ( f, 'csv_ingest', sep=',' )
        conn.commit ()
```

Data to be loaded in Postgres

Comment: first you should find row in data which makes problem. maybe if you will see this row then you will know what to do next.

Comment: The easiest fix, if available to you, would be to regenerate the CSV using another delimiter like TAB delimited or Pipe (|) delimited, etc. Then retry the upload after updating the sep= value in upload command.